# ArcMap 10 / ArcGIS Pro 2.8 - identifying records for deletion

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-pro, field-calculator

I use Esri products, predominantly ArcMap, but am interested in how to sort this in ArcMap also (if it is different).

I have a shapefile of over 2800 polygons.  All the polygons have a reference such as 0/1, 130,292.  0/1 and 1/0 represent the same thing, as does 131/292 and 292/131.

How would you go about removing the duplicates?

Comment: You have a text field with the values `131/292` and another row is `292/131`, and you want to delete the `292/131` row completely? Can you add a screenshot showing the attribute table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use arcpy to update your ref field with sorted characters:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\folder\shape123.shp' #Change
ref_field = r'somefieldname' #Change

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ref_field) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = ''.join(sorted(row[0])  #Update ref_field with sorted characters, for example '131/292' will become '/112239'                         
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Then use [Find Identical](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/find-identical.htm) or [Delete Identical](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/delete-identical.htm) with your updated field as input.